# How to UNION with multiple CTE tables?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently trying to UNION using 2 different CTE tables.

Here is what my current query looks like (below):

I however get an error in Snowflake and am not sure what is wrong with the syntax of my query.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

````
CREATE TABLE TABLE 1 AS (
  WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
  USER, 
  DATE,
  FLAG 1
  FROM TABLE 2 OWN 
  INNER JOIN TABLE 3 ACT ON OWN.USER=ACT.USER
  INNER JOIN TABLE 4 SUB ON SUB.USER=OWN.USER)
  SELECT USER, 
  DATE,
  FLAG 1, 
  (CASE WHEN DATE >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HAS_PLAYED_30_DAYS,
  (CASE WHEN DATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HAS_NOT_PLAYED_30_DAYS
  FROM CTE)
  UNION
  WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 
    USER, 
   DATE,
  FLAG 1
      FROM TABLE 5 OWN 
  INNER JOIN TABLE 6 ACT ON OWN.USER=ACT.USER
  INNER JOIN TABLE 7 SUB ON SUB.USER=OWN.USER)
  SELECT USER, 
  DATE,
  FLAG 1, 
  (CASE WHEN DATE >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HAS_PLAYED_30_DAYS,
  (CASE WHEN DATE < CURRENT_DATE - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HAS_NOT_PLAYED_30_DAYS
  FROM CTE);```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple CTEs are handled as:

```
with cte1 as (
      . . . 
     ),
     cte2 as (
      . . .
     ),
     . . .
select . . .
from cte1
union all
select . . .
from cte2
. . .
```

and so on.  Note that `union all` is much preferred over `union` because it does not incur overhead to remove duplicates.

There are also errors such as `flag 1` and `table 1`.  I assume those are just part of transcribing the question for public consumption.

Comment: Thank you for your help Gordon! Indeed, as you mentioned, the errors with flag 1 and table 1 are just transcribing errors because of data sensitivity. When it comes to the syntax for declaring my 2 different CTEs, is the syntax you sent above exact? I am using exactly what you sent but I keep getting an "SQL compilation error: Object 'CTE2' does not exist or not authorized" error.

Comment: @JustineMit . . . CTEs are quite standard across databases.  I don't know of a Snowflake environment for testing, but here is an example in Postgres:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=67b0d4c3c79ed7b2f1bad91915d1c797.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon!